# servlet writes html form to Android

Tags: android, servlets

I would like to write servlet's output to android activity. But in the activity, i m getting only html stream of data. How can i display the html web page display in Android?

NewServlet.java

```
    @WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
    public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<html>\n" +
            "    <body>\n" +
            "        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"click me\" />\n" +
            "    </body>\n" +
            "</html>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bright.myurldemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        BackProcess backProcess = new BackProcess();
        backProcess.execute();

    }
    boolean flag = true;
    String string;
    class BackProcess extends AsyncTask{
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            try{
                URL url = new URL("http://10.11.55.45:8080/WebApplication3/NewServlet");
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;
                int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                        output.append(s);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                flag = false;
                string = e.getMessage();
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            if(flag)
                textView.setText(output);
            else
                textView.setText(string);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display the web page itself, like in a browser. You cannot accomplish this, using a text view. You need to use a component called WebView.

Here's a short example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webpage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webpage);
webView.loadUrl("http://10.11.55.45:8080/WebApplication3/NewServlet");
```

Comment: Happy to help :) You can accept the answer, if it solved your case.